# d3.select does not grab right tag

Tags: d3.js

I am working on javascript project.

What I have done so far with d3.js is drawing a world map.
I reference the following page.(http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/a-simple-d3js-map-explained.html)

All countries are drawn under svg tag.

What I would like to do is convert the image to png and download to local computer.

Researching in the Internet, it id doable.

I need to convert it to base64 datarurl and then convert it to png.

The first thing I have to do is select svg tag.

The following is my code

```
function downloadImg(){     
        var html = d3.select("svg")
                .attr("version", 1.1)
                .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
                .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

        window.alert(html);
        ...
        ...
}
```

For testing purpose, I print out "html".
What it give to me is the entire body.
I just need to have svg tag elements.

Can you tell me what I have done wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) is your friend here:

```
var html = d3.select("svg")
                .attr("version", 1.1)
                .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
                .node().outerHTML
```